# Cochrane-Orcutt transformation in R, compute BIC for model

Tags: r

I am constructing a linear model in R.  I deal with autocorrelation using the orcutt package:

```
require(orcutt)
model.lm <- lm(y ~  x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
coch1 = cochrane.orcutt(model.lm, convergence = 8)
```

I want to find the BIC value for both model.lm and coch1, however, this is what happens:

I can easily extract the BIC from model.lm.

```
> BIC(model.lm)
[1] 2402.508
> class(model.lm)
[1] "lm"
```

However, I cannot easily extract the BIC from coch1.

```
> BIC(coch1)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "orcutt"
> class(coch1)
[1] "orcutt"
```

Because the class of coch1 is "orcutt", I cannot simply run BIC(coch1) like I was able to do for model.lm which is class "lm".  How can I compute the AIC and BIC values for the coch1 model?

Comment: I am pretty sure I figured out how to compute the AIC hand:

`AICvalueCOCH = nrow(Data)*(log(2*pi)+1+log((sum(coch1$residuals^2)/nrow(Data))))+((length(coch1$coefficients)+1)*2)` 

and the BIC by hand:    

`BICvalueCOCH = nrow(Data)*(log(2*pi)+1+log((sum(coch1$residuals^2)/nrow(Data))))+((length(coch1$coefficients)+1)*log(nrow(Data)))`

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I figured out how to compute the AIC hand:

```
AICvalueCOCH = nrow(Data)*(log(2*pi)+1+log((sum(coch1$residuals^2)/nrow(Data))))+((length(coch1$coefficients)+1)*2)
```

and the BIC by hand:

```
BICvalueCOCH = nrow(Data)*(log(2*pi)+1+log((sum(coch1$residuals^2)/nrow(Data))))+((length(coch1$coefficients)+1)*log(nrow(Data)))
```